# Popover in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, popover

I want to create a popover in Xamarin.forms. I have used [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started) but this is just a popup. I want to implement something similar to iOS popover. Can anybody guide me on this?
Thanks

I want something like this
[image]

Comment: What's the difference between what Rg.Plugins.Popup does, and an iOS Popover?

Comment: @Bejasc iOS popover we can show with an arrow that pointing to the clicked button. And it starts with the position of the clicked button origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit). 
The last example is exactly what you require.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you can do for the arrow, but refer to [this answer](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/262) on the Rg.Plugins.Popup issues board.

Set a position of the popup and move its position using `TranslationX`, `TranslationY` or `AbsoluteLayout`

---

For displaying popups, Rg.Plugins.Popup is normally exactly the plugin I would recommend to people for its ease of use and application to the sort of thing you're trying to do, but you've already stumbled upon that.